# Pass pointer to on-stack variable for new thread - is this code safe?

Tags: c, networking, pthreads

Consider the following code:

```
void* echo_data(void* client_socket) {
    // for the sake of argument - suppose there's a lot of code here before we copy the socket to local variable:
    int socket = *(int*)client_socket;
    // send back whatever is coming from client
    return (void*)0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int server_socket = establish_connection();

    while (1) {
        int incoming_client_socket = wait_for_connection(server_socket);
        fprintf(stdout, "new connection accepted...\n");

        pthread_t client_thread;
        pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, echo_data, (void*)&incoming_client_socket);
    }
}
```

I know I am ignoring return codes here, but this code doesn't actually run (there's no `establish_connection` or `wait_for_connection`) and was put together to convey an idea, so for the sake of argument let's say all functions always succeed...
I do, however, wonder specifically about the implication of using local variable as argument for a newly created thread.
Consider the following scenario:

1. `wait_for_connection` accepts new connection and returns `incoming_client_socket`.
2. `incoming_client_socket` is passed "by reference" to `echo_data` in a newly created thread, while it is currently stored on `main()`'s stuck.
3. Now suppose that it takes some time until `echo_data` copies the data pointed by `client_socket`, and in the meantime, the main thread accepts another connection, which will overrun the previous `incoming_client_socket` - the thread then copies wrong data.

Is that a real concern?
if not, how come?
If so, what's a safe way of doing that?

Comment: You can pass the value directly instead of passing its address.

Comment: Good point, but what if I have more than just `int` to pass? for example, a struct containing socket and some more other connection-related attributes?

Comment: In that case, create a structure pointer for each connection, allocate memory and fill the values and pass the pointer to he threads.

Comment: Yeah, it's not always a bad idea, but very often it is.  This is not an exceptional case, and you should follow @Karthick plan:)  Your 'client_thread()' can free the pointer to its context struct just before it terminates on connection close/whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that a real concern?

Yes. Its not a safe way of doing it.

You can pass the value directly instead of passing its address.

```
pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, echo_data, (void*) incoming_client_socket);`
```

and the thread function should be like

```
void* echo_data(void* client_socket) {
  int socket = (int)client_socket;
  /* your code */
}
```

If you wish to pass more than one elements to the thread, then you could wrap it inside a structure, create a structure pointer for it, allocate memory and fill the values and pass the pointer to the threads.

```
struct X {
  int socket;
  /* other members here*/
};
```

and

```
  while (1) {
    int incoming_client_socket = wait_for_connection(server_socket);
    fprintf(stdout, "new connection accepted...\n");
    struct X *ptr = malloc (sizeof(struct X));
    ptr->socket = incoming_client_socket;
    /* other assignment here */

    pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, echo_data, (void*)ptr);
  }
```

And your thread func should look like

```
void* echo_data(void* client_socket) {
  // for the sake of argument - suppose there's a lot of code here before we copy the socket to local variable:
  struct X *ptr = (struct X *)client_socket;
  // send back whatever is coming from client
  return (void*)0;
}
```

Don't forget to free the memory.

Comment: round trip `int` → `void*` → `int` is not guaranteed and is just ugly. Casts are evil and should be avoided where ever they can. Often they just hide things under the carpet. This also holds for your last code snippet, the two casts bring nothing.

Comment: @Jens: Indeed, but it's vastly more efficient & less error-prone than the alternatives. It's a shame the arg is `void *` and not a union with `uintmax_t`...